# Pivot DATA to get desired End View

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

My data in Database Table ...

```
SELECT [Quote Reference Number] 
      ,[Value]
      ,[Method]
      ,[Country]
      ,[SubRegion]
      ,[Route 1 or Route2]
      ,[TYPE A or B ]
  FROM Table 1
```

My Desired Summary view

WORLD VIEW

```
Subregion | Country | Count of Route1 + Type A quotes | Count of Route1 + Type B quotes|  Count of Route2 + Type A quotes | Count of Route2 + Type B quotes| All Routes & Types |
```

EMEA VIEW

```
Subregion | Country | Count of Route1 + Type A quotes | Count of Route1 + Type B quotes| Count of Route2 + Type A quotes | Count of Route2 + Type B quotes| All Routes & Types |
```

I could do this by creating a table with 2 rows and just doing lots of sql queries to populate all the fields but was told it could be done by Pivoting in the database but dont know how exactly ?

Can anyone offer some assistance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot in the case would be difficult (but not impossible) because the `FOR... IN` clauses contains a field and a set of values respectively, not Conditional statements.  You're better of with a `sum/case` e.g.

```
SELECT 
      [Country]
      ,[SubRegion]
      ,SUM (CASE WHEN [Route 1 or Route2] = 'Route1' AND [TYPE A or B ] = 'A' 
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
              as [Count of Route1 + Type A quotes ]
      ,SUM (CASE WHEN [Route 1 or Route2] = 'Route1' AND [TYPE A or B ] = 'B' 
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
              as [Count of Route1 + Type B quotes ]
     ,SUM (CASE WHEN [Route 1 or Route2] = 'Route2' AND [TYPE A or B ] = 'A' 
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
              as [Count of Route2 + Type A quotes ]
      ,SUM (CASE WHEN [Route 1 or Route2] = 'Route2' AND [TYPE A or B ] = 'B' 
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
              as [Count of Route2 + Type B quotes]
      ,COUNT(*)  All Routes & Types
  FROM [Table 1]
  GROUP BY
       [Country]
      ,[SubRegion]
```

Comment: I think you are right with this approach . Tested it and it seems pretty good to me !